# Unable to increment questions from sqlite database in quiz using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I'm still working on my quiz program but I'm currently having an issue with getting the program to increment the questions which are retrieved from a database that I also have. When I try to move to the next record in my database I haven't been able to actually change the contents of the page, everything stays as it is and I have to this point not been able to rectify the issue. I feel as though it's an issue with my use of variable but I cant think of any way around this. Here's the section of my code where I'm having this issue:

```
class ques(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    fetchrecNum = "SELECT MAX(qnumber) FROM questions"
    cursor.execute(fetchrecNum)
    self.recNum=str(cursor.fetchall())
    self.recNum=self.recNum.strip("[('")
    self.recNum=self.recNum.strip("',)]")
    self.recNum=int(self.recNum)
    recordNum = tk.Label(self, text = self.recNum)
    recordNum.pack()

    self.Qn = 1
    self.quizScore = 0

    fetchQ = "SELECT questioncontent FROM questions WHERE qnumber=?"
    cursor.execute(fetchQ, [self.Qn])
    Q=str(cursor.fetchall())
    Q=Q.strip("[('")
    Q=Q.strip("',)]")
    question = tk.Label(self, text = Q)
    question.pack()

    fetchA1 = "SELECT qanswer1 FROM questions WHERE qnumber=?"
    cursor.execute(fetchA1, [self.Qn])
    A1=str(cursor.fetchall())
    A1=A1.strip("[('")
    A1=A1.strip("',)]")
    answer1 = tk.Label(self, text = A1)
    answer1.pack()

    fetchA2 = "SELECT qanswer2 FROM questions WHERE qnumber=?"
    cursor.execute(fetchA2, [self.Qn])
    A2=str(cursor.fetchall())
    A2=A2.strip("[('")
    A2=A2.strip("',)]")
    answer2 = tk.Label(self, text = A2)
    answer2.pack()

    fetchA3 = "SELECT qanswer3 FROM questions WHERE qnumber=?"
    cursor.execute(fetchA3, [self.Qn])
    A3=str(cursor.fetchall())
    A3=A3.strip("[('")
    A3=A3.strip("',)]")
    answer3 = tk.Label(self, text = A3)
    answer3.pack()

    fetchA4 ="SELECT qanswer4 FROM questions WHERE qnumber=?"
    cursor.execute(fetchA4, [self.Qn])
    A4=str(cursor.fetchall())
    A4=A4.strip("[('")
    A4=A4.strip("',)]")
    answer4 = tk.Label(self, text = A4)
    answer4.pack()

    fetchcA ="SELECT correctans FROM questions WHERE qnumber=?"
    cursor.execute(fetchcA, [self.Qn])
    self.cA=str(cursor.fetchall())
    self.cA=self.cA.strip("[('")
    self.cA=self.cA.strip("',)]")



def confirmAnswer(self):
    answerGiven = self.enterAnswer
    correctAnswer = self.cA
    if answerGiven == correctAnswer:
        self.rightOrWrong.configure(text ="Correct")
        self.quizScore = (self.quizScore + 1)
    else:
        self.rightOrWrong.configure(text="Incorrect")
    if self.Qn < self.recNum:
        self.Qn = (self.Qn+1)
        lambda: controller.show_frame(ques)
    else:
        self.rightOrWrong.configure(text="Quiz Complete! Your score was: " + str(self.quizScore))
```

I'm not sure how else i could go about trying to get the contents of the page to change but i hope i can learn from someone else here as nobody around me is very helpful at all (including teachers) and this is the best option I have. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you'd want to help yourself please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can't you get all in one query ? And you should do this in separated function (with parameter) which you could execute many times to get different questions. In `__init__` you shpuld put only empty labels.

Comment: why do you convert fetchall into `str()` ? Without this you shouldn't need to strip `[(` and `)]`. It looks like you have to find tutorial and learn how to work with database.

Comment: `fetchall()[0][0]` or use `fetchone` to get only one row - `fetchone()[0]` - but it shows that you have to get database's tutorial and learn basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it but I would do something like in code.

In `__init__` I create empty labels and execute separated method which reads data from database and puts them in labels. later I can use this method to get next question.

To get one row from database you can use `fetchone()`. To get data from row you don't have to use `str()` and `strip()` but index `row[0]`, `row[1]`, etc. You may have to change indexes if you have columns in different order in database.

```
class ques(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.Qn = 1
        self.quizScore = 0
        self.correctAnswer = ''  # <-- create it at start (and use better name)

        # v-- create empty labels

        self.recordNum = tk.Label(self, text='')
        self.recordNum.pack()

        self.question = tk.Label(self, text='')
        self.question.pack()

        self.answer1 = tk.Label(self, text='')
        self.answer1.pack()

        self.answer2 = tk.Label(self, text='')
        self.answer2.pack()

        self.answer3 = tk.Label(self, text='')
        self.answer3.pack()

        self.answer4 = tk.Label(self, text='')
        self.answer4.pack()

        self.update_question_number() # <-- get question number
        self.update_question()        # <-- get new question

    def update_question_number(self)
        # Get question's number

        query = "SELECT MAX(qnumber) FROM questions"
        cursor.execute(query)
        row = cursor.fetchone()

        self.recordNum['text'] = row[0]

    def update_question(self):
        # Get new question

        query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE qnumber=?"
        cursor.execute(query, (self.Qn,))
        row = cursor.fetchone()

        self.question['text'] = row[0]

        self.answer1['text'] = row[1]
        self.answer2['text'] = row[2]
        self.answer3['text'] = row[3]
        self.answer4['text'] = row[4]

        self.correctAnswer = row[5]    

    def confirmAnswer(self):

        if self.enterAnswer == self.correctAnswer:
            self.rightOrWrong['text'] = "Correct"
            self.quizScore += 1
        else:
            self.rightOrWrong['text'] = "Incorrect"

        if self.Qn < self.recNum:
            self.Qn += 1           # <-- get new question
            self.update_question() # <-- get new question
            #lambda: controller.show_frame(ques) # ??? do you have to change frame ???
        else:
            self.rightOrWrong.['text'] = "Quiz Complete! Your score was: {}".format(self.quizScore)
```